# Wcf Endpoint and configuring challenge , please help a WCF newbie

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am new to WCF so please bear with me.

I have  StudentData.svc.vb that implements 2 interfaces from the same IStudentData.vb

The 2 Interfaces are IStudentData and IHeartbeat
Heartbeat is a 1 way Operational Contract    _

I am using IIS 7.5 to host this service
the web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</
```

my app.config after creating the service reference is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IStudentData" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHeartbeat" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://www.ortho-sync.com:8080/StudentData.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IStudentData"
                contract="oStudentData.IStudentData" name="BasicHttpBinding_IStudentData" />
            <endpoint address="http://www.ortho-sync.com:8080/StudentData.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHeartbeat"
                contract="oStudentData.IHeartbeat" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHeartbeat" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

IStudentData  has a class with a datamember of byte array that I am using to transfer an image.
If I use a small file it transfers and everything works
if I use a 1 meg image I get (413) Request Entity Too Large

I have played with the bindings and end points til I am blue in the face,
anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is picking up the default values for the bindings because you have not specified your own default `basicHttpBinding` or created an endpoint (in the service) that references your own `basicHttpBinding`.

You can make a binding configuration the default configuration for that binding by omitting the `name` attribute, like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
```

Alternatively, you can create an endpoint explicitly and set the binding configuration for that endpoint by using the `bindingConfiguration` attribute:

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"  
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IStudentData"
          contract="oStudentData.IStudentData" 
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IStudentData" />
```

The second example assumes a binding configuration defined with a `name` of `BasicHttpBinding_IStudentData`.

You would use either of these in your **service** config file.

Comment: ok so I tried the first option amd it worked with files 1-10 megs on a 65 meg file I get the following error ---------------------------
WCFService_Tester
---------------------------
There was no endpoint listening at http://www.ortho-sync.com:8080/StudentData.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------                                                                    so do u think option 2 will fix this instead of option 1?

Comment: what do I put for binding configuration

Comment: I would suggest you break up large files into chunks. Dont try to download 65MB in a single call!

Comment: what about transfermode= streaming?